# system.web.extentions.dll not getting published!

Tags: asp.net, deployment, publish

I use the publish option of asp.net 2.0 to create a deployable copy of my web application. Lately I've noticed that the System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll and the System.Web.Extensions.dll does not get copied when using the publish option. 
Has anyone any idea why this could have happened? 
Couldn't google anything definite about this too...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They're part of the framework, so they are not published.

Comment: They used to get published before.. why did it stop doing that all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out they are part of the .NET framework and installed into the GAC which is why they aren't copied in a publish. Visual Studio expects them to be installed in the same location on the deployment target.

That said you can change this, right-click on the reference go to Properties and change the **Copy Local** to **true**. This will put a copy of the assembly in the local bin of the website and copy it when you publish.